# Get Values from Collection Field in a Class

Tags: c#, string, collections

I need to get a collection type data from a property/field and eventually
display it on a form. How do I do that?

The code below explains what I am trying to do and errors I got, hope it makes sense.

```
public class C
{

    public string Id { get; set; }
    //public List<string> ColVal { get; }

    public C()
    {}

    public C(ObjectA objVar)
    {
        Id = objVar.Id;
        //ColVal = objVar.ColVals; //<- Errors out: This is a collection type property, how do I get values & solve this?
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need a setter for your ColVal property, first off. Secondly, I am still not sure what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: What is `ObjectA`?  Does it have a `ColVals` property?  What is it's type?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what ObjectA is, but it looked like it should be of type C, so I changed that. Then I noticed your collection property did not have a setter.

public class C {

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public List<string> ColVal { get; set; }

public C()
{}

public C(C objVar)
{
    Id = objVar.Id;
   ColVal = objVar.ColVal; //<- Errors out: This is a collection type property, how do I get values & solve this?
}
}
```

Comment: ObjectA is a class which comes from an external dll which is referenced in the project.

objVar.ColVals: ColVals is a property of objVar and the signature from 
VS Object Browser browser is as below:

//public SomeCompany.SCData.Extensions.ExtensionCollection<MediaCategory> Tags { get; }

It has a getter but not a setter.

I need to extract the values of objVar.ColVals and get it displayed on a form
objVar.ColVals I suspect is a string of Tags that I need displayed on s form.